# While converting json string to object \u003c is getting converted to < How to stop this conversion?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

```
 {"userName":"1_jan_\u003cscript>alert(1)\u003c/script>
```

I have used

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            User user = mapper.readValue(input, User.class);
```

and

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

I doesn't want \u003c to get converted to <.

Please help me in doing it.

Comment: From a Java perspective `\u003c` and `<` are exactly the same character.  Can you explain why you need the escaped version?

Comment: I am trying to avoid json injections using Json Sanitizer class there the "<" is getting converted to "\u003c" I am comparing the normal json string and the sanitized json string to get the key fields in which the json string is getting injected  Normal Json String: "{"userName":"1_jan_<script>alert(1)</script>based_kwd_bidding_apr_1"} Sanitized Json String: {"userName":"1_jan_\u003cscript>alert(1)\u003c/script>based_kwd_bidding_apr_1"} I want to compare these two strings and the field name user name as the javascript injection has taken place in that field.

Comment: The JSON you've provided represents a string that includes `<`. When decoding it, the value *should* include `<`. You should give more details about what you're trying to do within the question, but fundamentally the JSON parser is doing exactly the right thing. (What else could the resulting string contain?)

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
Gson g= new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Lia.  I have tried using that option but the \u003c  is automatically getting converted to < while I am converting the Json string to Java Object